# Как убрать конкретное слово из предложения пользователя и использовать его в дальнейшем?

Tags: python

Есть бот, который должен после сообщения пользователя, например: "Загугли Мадонну" достать статью из википедии по запросу "Мадонна".
Прописал так:

```py
def filter(message):
    if "загугли".lower() in message.text.lower():
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, getwiki(message.text))
```

но, тут бот гуглит по всему сообщению пользователя, если там есть слово "загугли"

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Нашёл ответ в функции "re.sub"

```
    if "загугли".lower() in message.text.lower():
    result = re.sub(r'загугли', '',message.text)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, getwiki(result))
```

теперь другая проблема - убирает это слово только в точном соответствии. Как сделать, чтоб в любом регистре убирало?

```
result = re.sub(r'загугли'**.lower()**, '',message.text)
```

добавление lower не помогает

**UPD:**
Таки нашёл ответ:

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text']) 
def handle_text(message): 
    if "загугли".lower() in message.text.lower(): 
        result = re.sub(r'загугли', '',message.text.lower())
```

Comment: Таки нашёл ответ:
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def handle_text(message):
    if "загугли".lower() in message.text.lower():
        result = re.sub(r'загугли', '',message.text.lower())

Answer (score 0):

Сначала вам нужно убрать слово "загугли". Для этого:

```py
import re


def remove__googleit(s):
    return re.sub('\bзагугли\b', '', re.I)
```

А дальше – приведите слова в начальную форму. Для этого можно сделать одно из двух:

1. По словарю.
2. С помощью NLTK.